# Program to separate digits of a number using asterisk

Tags: c

I am building a program that will ask the user to input a 5 digit positive number. It will then display each of the digits separated by an asterisk. For example, if the user inputs `51408`, the output will be `5*1*4*0*8`.

But, I can't seem to get the logic of finding the separate digits (of the number). How should I do it?

Now, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int mnumber, num5, num4, num3, num2, num1;

    printf("Input number:");
    scanf ("%d", &mnumber);

    //these are the ones that i have trouble with i can't seem to get the logic//
    num5 = (mnumber/10000) / 1;
    num4 = (mnumber/1000) / 1;
    num3 = (mnumber/100) / 1;
    num2 = (mnumber/10) / 1;
    num1 = (mnumber/1) / 1;

    printf("=%d", num5); 
    printf("*%d", num4); 
    printf("*%d", num3); 
    printf("*%d", num2); 
    printf("*%d", num1); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at C's `%` (modulus) operator. See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html.

Comment: what happens if the user types in 10, 123, 1200, or 1234567 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem using your approach, you have to remove the most significant part of the number, once you have processed it. For example:

```
num5 = mnumber/10000;
mnumber -= num5*10000;
num4  = mnumber/1000;
mnumber -= num4*1000;
num3 = mnumber/100;
mnumber -= num3*100;
num2 = mnumber/10;
mnumber -= num2*10;
num1 = mnumber;
```

However, I think it would be cleaner to convert to a string and then print out each character of that string, alternating with an asterisk, as @clcto demonstrates.

Comment: isn't that a really brute force solution?

Comment: @AnthonyLambert Yes, that is not an elegant solution. It writes it all out explicitly without looping. I just wanted to show the asker how to correct their version. I would do it the way clcto demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the number to a string (or possibly read in the input as a string and do validation on it), and then print it one character at a time:

```
 char input_str[15];
 sprintf( input_str, "%d", mnumber );

 int len = strlen( input_str );
 if( len > 0 )
     printf( "%c", input_str[0] );

 for( int i = 1; i < len; ++i )
     printf( "*%c", input_str[i] );
```

Comment: If it is irrelevant that the string is really values then this is a good solution....

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Method: Using Strings

Instead of going into all that hassle, you could take the input as a [string](http://cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) (`char` array). That will make your work much more easier and neater.

### Steps for Solving

Here's what I suggest you to do:

**1.**  Read the input into a string 6 characters long.

**2.**  Print '*=*' i.e. the equals sign.

**3.**  Use a loop to print the digits one-by-one, each preceded by an
    asterisk.

### Sample Code

If you follow the steps above, you will come up with something like this...

```
int main(void)
{
    //taking string input//
    char num[6];
    printf("Input number:");
    scanf("%s", num);

    //printing = and first digit//
    printf("=");
    printf("%c", num[0]);

    //printing * and digit// 
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
        printf("%c", num[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus `%` operator to make your life easier.

```
num5 = (mnumber/10000);
num4 = (mnumber/1000) % 10;
num3 = (mnumber/100) % 10;
num2 = (mnumber/10) % 10;
num1 = (mnumber/1) % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
char str[50];
char tmp[50];
str[0] = '=';
str[1] = 0;
while (mnumber>0)
{
     int n = mnumber % 10;
     mnumber /= 10;
     if (mnumber>0)
        sprintf (tmp,"%s%d*", str, n );
     else
        sprintf (tmp,"%s%d", str, n );
     strcpy ( str, tmp);
}
printf ("%s\n",str);
```

Comment: this assumes that it being a value is important and not just a string of chars... with '*' between them?